# Extracting polymorphic types in json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

I am using json4s to work with JSON objects in my Scala code. I want to convert JSON data to an internal representation. The following learning test illustrates my problem:

```
"Polimorphic deserailization" should "be possible" in {
    import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.write
    val json =
      """
        |{"animals": [{
        |  "name": "Pluto"
        |  }]
        |}
      """.stripMargin
    implicit val format = Serialization.formats(ShortTypeHints(List(classOf[Dog], classOf[Bird])))
    val animals = parse(json) \ "animals"
    val ser = write(Animals(Dog("pluto") :: Bird(canFly = true) :: Nil))
    System.out.println(ser)
    // animals.extract[Animal] shouldBe Dog("Pluto") // Does not deserialize, because Animal cannot be constructed
}
```

Suppose there is a JSON object which has a list of Animals. `Animal` is an abstract type, and hence cannot be instantiated. Instead, I want to parse the JSON structure to return either `Dog` or `Bird` objects. They have a different signature:

```
case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal
case class Bird(canFly: Boolean) extends Animal
```

Because their signature is distinct, they can be identified without having a class Tag in the JSON object. (To be precise, the JSON structure I receive does not provide those tags).

I tried to serialize a list of Animal objects (see the code). The result is: `Ser: {"animals":[{"jsonClass":"Dog","name":"pluto"},{"jsonClass":"Bird","canFly":true}]}`

As you can see, when serializing, json4s adds the class-tag `jsonClass`.

**How can I deserialize a JSON object that does not provide such a tag?** Is it possible to achieve this by extending `TypeHints`?

I also found a similar question: [[json4s]:Extracting Array of different objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591859/json4sextracting-array-of-different-objects) with a solution that somehow uses generics instead of subclassing. However, if I understand correctly, this solution does not allow to simply pass the json object and have an internal representation. Instead I would need to select the form that is not `None` (while checking all possible Types in the inheritance hiearchy. This is a bit tedious, since I have multiple Polymorphic classes at different depths in the JSON structure.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to that? I'm facing the same challenge here...

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find an answer. As a workaround I agreed with the guy that created the serialized JSON to add type hints; but this is obviously not a solution if you can't influence the JSON scheme. I'm still interested in an answer and have a bit more knowledge about json4s than I had at the time of writing the question, so I'll try to come up with a solution.

Comment: @borck Thank you for reviving the question. I found extending `CustomSerializer` to be a fairly simple solution (though the code for extracting large polymorphic structures may become a bit bloated). I hope this also helps you solving your problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ultimately, on the project that lead to this question, I agreed with the guy creating the serialized JSON on adding type hints for all polymorphic types. In retrospect this solution is probably the cleanest because it enables future extension of the JSON schema without dangers of introducing ambiguity.

Nevertheless, there exists a fairly simple solution (not just a workaround) to the actual problem.

The type `org.json4s.Formats`, which is an implicit value in our scope, provides a function `+(org.json4s.Serializer[A])`. This function allows us to add new custom serializers. So for each polymorphic supertype (in our case this concerns only `Animal`), we can define a custom serializer. In our example, where we have

```
trait Animal
case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal
case class Bird(canFly: Boolean) extends Animal
```

a custom serializer that operates without type hints would look as follows:

```
class AnimalSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Animal](format => ( {
  case JObject(List(JField("name", JString(name)))) => Dog(name)
  case JObject(List(JField("canFly", JBool(canFly)))) => Bird(canFly)
}, {
  case Dog(name) => JObject(JField("name", JString(name)))
  case Bird(canFly) => JObject(JField("canFly", JBool(canFly)))
}))
```

Thanks to the function `+` we can add multiple custom serializers, while keeping the default serializers.

```
case class AnimalList(animals: List[Animal])

val json =
  """
    |{"animals": [
    |  {"name": "Pluto"},
    |  {"name": "Goofy"},
    |  {"canFly": false},
    |  {"name": "Rover"}
    |  ]
    |}
  """.stripMargin
implicit val format = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints) + new AnimalSerializer
println(parse(json).extract[AnimalList])
```

prints

```
AnimalList(List(Dog(Pluto), Dog(Goofy), Bird(false), Dog(Rover)))
```

Comment: This works indeed, thanks for pursuing your investigation... I feel like the type hints work better if you have a grip on the json producer though as this will indeed become rapidly bloated...

Comment: Note also that this works because the serialized types for Dog and Bird are different (JString v/s JBool). In the more general case, you'll need to also serialize the name of the type in order to discern between them.

Comment: Also note and be aware that the _deserialize_ part of your custom serializer class,  expects the JSON data to be in the order of how you organized your pattern match. 
more details here: [link](https://nmatpt.com/blog/2017/01/29/json4s-custom-serializer/)

Comment: To reduce the amount of boilerplaty-code: 
1) When using the technique in the previous comment, you could case-class extraction in the deserializer part of the customSerializer class.

2) For the serializer part of the customSeriealizer class you could use the DSL to produce JValues::  [more info about DSL](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#dsl-rules)